# How to combine AreaChart and LineChart with gwt-visualizations

Tags: java, vaadin, google-visualization

I have a vaadin project where I use visualizations-for-vaadin addon, which is a wrapper for gwt-visualizations. What I need is an AreaChart with stacked areas and one reference line on it. So kind of combination of an AreaChart and a LineChart. I understood, that if I want to achieve this, I have to write/extend my own AreaLineChart. Can somebody point me into the right solution how to do it? I am browsing through the visualizations code, but still cannot find out how to do it.

The specs for the chart would be something like this:

```
class AreaLineChart {

    public void addArea(...);

    public void add(....);

    // this is the new method I need in the area chart
    public void addLine(....);
}
```

Thank you,
Filip

Comment: So I have found out, that there actually is a ComboChart, that provides this functionality in gwt-visualizations, but there is no wrapper for that in visualizations-for-vaadin addon. So probably I will have to write this wrapper. Still, any thoughts on which way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider switching charting packages, the [Invient charts addon](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/337100) is a wrapper for the High Charts package, which is very pretty looking. Conveniently, it already wraps the combo chart for you. See [the demo here](http://charts-invient.appspot.com/demo) and click on the combination charts at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AreaChart where you can define areaOpacity to 0 for drawing a line.
But for this you need to use the "series" option.